# Mac and Windows backup

Tags: backup

I have a Mac and a PC at home, and I am thinking of getting a NAS like (GoFlex Home Network Storage System or Western Digital My Book Live) to back up both machines.

If I were to use Time Machine to backup on the NAS system, would the Windows be able to backup to the same NAS? If you know of any good ways to backup both PC and Mac, do let me know as well.

Answer (score -1):

One easy way to do this would have separate shares: one for Time Machine to back up your Macs and another for another program to back up your PCs.

(The shares could be separate partitions or separate folders on a single partition; it depends on how your NAS is set up.)

Comment: I see. So it's possible to setup the NAS into dedicated partition for Mac and Windows?

Comment: @revolver I assume so. I've never set up a NAS.